# display wordpress posts by sub category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress, I am using wordpress Version 4.5, I like to display posts by subcategories, anyone please help how can I do this.
This is what I want

**PARENT CATEGORY NAME**

*SUB CATEGORY 1*

```
Post 1

Post 2
```

*SUB CATEGORY 2*

```
Post 3

Post 4
```

*SUB CATEGORY 3*

```
Post 5

Post 6
```

...

Thanks in advance

Comment: check category__in

Comment: You should have write your own plugin for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am not wrong you need this, you need double loop to fetch the posts under subcategories

this is how you get current page category

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $catID = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
?>
```

and then do this by using above catID

```
<?php 
$subcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $catID);
    foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
        echo '<h3>' . $subcat->cat_name . '</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
            $subcat_posts = get_posts('cat=' . $subcat->cat_ID);
            foreach($subcat_posts as $subcat_post) {
                $postID = $subcat_post->ID;
                    echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($postID) . '">';
                        echo get_the_title($postID);
                        echo '</a>';
                    echo '</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: thank you, it is working, but after showing all posts by sub category, it display the posts under parent category again, like this 

Sub category 1

Post 1

Post 2

Sub category 2

Post 3

Post 4

Parent category

Post 1

Post 2

post 3

post 4

Comment: I don't want to display the posts again under parent category, help

Comment: Also check you hierarchy in categories, you might have a subcategory with same name as the parent category ??

Comment: plaese go to http://www.enterhelix.com/shan/wordpress4.5/category/surgerical-instrument/ 
parent category - surgerical instrument
child category under "surgerical instrument" - Abdominal Retractors, Bandage Scissors

Comment: no I have only 1 parent category and 2 sub categories under the parent

Comment: and this is the only code (as in answer) you have used on the page ?

Comment: $categories =  get_categories();  
    foreach  ($categories as $category){
    echo '<h3 class="sub-cat-name">&raquo; '.$category->name.'</h3>';
    foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<h4 class="title"><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>';
    echo '<div class="post-thumb">';
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">';
    if (has_post_thumbnail()){
    the_post_thumbnail();
    }
    echo '</a>';
    echo "</div>";
    }}

Comment: you are fetching all the categories here $categories = get_categories(); and not child categories , you should fetch only child categories.

Comment: if I use "child_of" parameter, no posts are displayed, if I remove it, the script is working, but at the bottom all posts under parent is display

Comment: did you try echo $catID ?? What does it display ?

Comment: yes, it display the parent category ID, ie 5, I tried this child_of=5, but does not work

Comment: and you sure you have child categories under this category id 5 ?

Comment: hello, I found the issue, actually the ID of parent category is 1, but it display 5, that's why no posts are appearing, that means
$categories = get_the_category();
$catID = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
echo $catID;
this prints a wrong output

Comment: you can see the display http://www.enterhelix.com/shan/wordpress4.5/category/surgerical-instrument/ , but at the top I wrote 
$categories = get_the_category();
$catID = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
echo $catID ;
which prints 5

Comment: If you like to join me on skype, please share your skype ID

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show all the categories that have subcategories with their respective subcategories that have posts with their respective posts, you can easily do that with the following function, as long as you know the slug of the taxonomy and the post type.

For example if you have a custom post type called 'books' and a custom taxonomy to classify your books called 'topic',

**then you would call this function using**

```
ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts( 'topic', 'book' );
```

That will display a list of all the topics with their respective subcategories followed by the books that belong to each subcategory.

Something like

Drama

- drama subcategory 1

  - book1
  - book2
  - book3
- drama subcategory 2

  - book4
  - book5

Comedy

- comedy subcategory 1

  - book6
  - book7
- comedy subcategory 2

  - book8
  - book9

**The following is the code for this:**

```
function ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts( $taxonomy, $post_type ) {

    // Get the top categories that belong to the provided taxonomy (the ones without parent)
    $categories = get_terms( 
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
            'parent'     => 0, // <-- No Parent
            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
            'hide_empty' => true // <!-- change to false to also display empty ones
        )
    );
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php
        // Iterate through all categories to display each individual category
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

            $cat_name = $category->name;
            $cat_id   = $category->term_id;
            $cat_slug = $category->slug;

            // Display the name of each individual category
            echo '<h3>Category: ' . $cat_name . ' - ID: ' . $cat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $cat_slug  . '</h3>'; 


            // Get all the subcategories that belong to the current category
            $subcategories = get_terms(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                    'parent'     => $cat_id, // <-- The parent is the current category
                    'orderby'    => 'term_id',
                    'hide_empty' => true
                )
            );
            ?>
            <div>
                <?php

                // Iterate through all subcategories to display each individual subcategory
                foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {

                    $subcat_name = $subcategory->name;
                    $subcat_id   = $subcategory->term_id;
                    $subcat_slug = $subcategory->slug;

                    // Display the name of each individual subcategory with ID and Slug
                    echo '<h4>Subcategory: ' . $subcat_name . ' - ID: ' . $subcat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $subcat_slug  . '</h4>';

                    // Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
                    $posts = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'post_type'      => $post_type,
                            'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
                            'hide_empty'     => true,
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query'      => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                    'terms'    => $subcat_id,
                                    'field'    => 'id'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );

                    // If there are posts available within this subcategory
                    if ( $posts->have_posts() ):
                        ?>
                        <div>
                            <?php

                            // As long as there are posts to show
                            while ( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post();

                                //Show the title of each post with the Post ID
                                ?>
                                <p>Post: <?php the_title(); ?> - ID: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
                                <?php

                            endwhile;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    else:
                        echo 'No posts found';
                    endif;

                    wp_reset_query();
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Then if you ONLY want to get the subcategories related to comedy, and you want to provide the 'comedy' slug as a filter to get something like:

- comedy subcategory 1

  - book6
  - book7
- comedy subcategory 2

  - book8
  - book9

**Then you would call the following function like this:**

```
ow_subcategories_with_posts_by_category( 'topic', 'book', 'comedy' );
```

**And the function to do that will be:**

```
function ow_subcategories_with_posts_by_category( $taxonomy, $post_type, $term ) {
    $category = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, $taxonomy );
    $cat_id   = $category->term_id;

    // Get all subcategories related to the provided $category ($term)
    $subcategories = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
            'parent'     => $cat_id,
            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
            'hide_empty' => true
        )
    );
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php
        // Iterate through all subcategories to display each individual subcategory
        foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {

            $subcat_name = $subcategory->name;
            $subcat_id   = $subcategory->term_id;
            $subcat_slug = $subcategory->slug;

            // Display the name of each individual subcategory with ID and Slug
            echo '<h4>Subcategory: ' . $subcat_name . ' - ID: ' . $subcat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $subcat_slug  . '</h4>';

            // Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
            $posts = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type'      => $post_type,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
                    'hide_empty'     => true,
                    'order'          => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query'      => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'terms'    => $subcat_id,
                            'field'    => 'id'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

            // If there are posts available within this subcategory
            if ( $posts->have_posts() ):
                ?>
                <div>
                    <?php
                    while ( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post();

                        //Show the title of each post with the Post ID
                        ?>
                        <p>Post: <?php the_title(); ?> - ID: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            else:
                echo 'No posts found';
            endif;

            wp_reset_query();
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```