# Display posts from sub category

Tags: wordpress

I have a travel site where I classify content by both country regions and travel activity types. My structure is something this:

- Beaches
- Food
- Region

  - US
  - Caribbean
  - Europe

I have a sidebar with recent posts and I'd like to pull posts only from the selected sub-category for that post that fall under "Region".

E.g. If in my post, I chose "Beaches" and "Caribbean" as my post categories, I'd like it to pull posts from "Caribbean" alone since that's the category falling under "Region". For reference here is what I usually use to pull out of the loop content.

```
 <?php global $post; $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )); query_posts( $args ); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

My custom sidebar posts

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042936/display-wordpress-posts-by-sub-category

Comment: Unfortunately their recommendation pulls for all sub-categories under a category and not for the specific one selected in the post.